# Grouping Mysql query contacts table by city

Tags: mysql, sql

an easy one, its long time i do not use mysql queries so maybe someone can help me out with this nooby question, i have a contacts table, id, name, and city.. i want to get all the contacts listed as follows.

```
city 1
--------
contact1
contact2
contact3

city 2
--------
contact4
contact7
contact10

city 3
--------
contact5
contact6
contact8
```

I do not want to use any additional php coding, just get the sql result like this

```
city 1 
   -> contact 1
   -> contact 2
   -> contact 3
city 2 
   -> contact 4
   -> contact 7
   -> contact 10
```

...

then fill the result in a php object and do like this:

```
foreach (cities as city)
{ 
   // code here
}
```

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use GROUP_CONCAT

```
SELECT  city, GROUP_CONCAT(name)
FROM    contacts
GROUP BY    city
```

Answer (score 0):

You just need to `GROUP BY` city column and use [GROUP_CONCAT](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.6/en/group-by-functions.html#function_group-concat) function in `SELECT` to get comma seprated list of names for each city.

```
SELECT city, GROUP_CONCAT(name) AS name
FROM contacts 
GROUP BY city;
```